# How do you duplicate player heads in minecraft on a windows keyboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I usually use a MacBook when I play and in order to duplicate a specific player head I would look at it and, while pressing command, press the key I have set to duplicate items. I need to know how to do this on a windows keyboard that doesn't have the command key.

Comment: By the way, I am looking for a way to do this **OUTSIDE** of my inventory.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (instead of <kbd>cmd</kbd>) then press the pick block button (mouse wheel click by default) with the player head highlighted.